# how to return number of certain values in an array using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, count

I need to return the number of non-reasonable (nan or out of range) values for the 3rd column where has 0s an a blank in it. I have to deal with a csv file in a real problem but I just created a ndarray for now.

```
data = np.array([[   1, 2000,  143, 4546], [   2, 1999,  246,    0], [   3, 2008,  190,    ], [   4, 2000,  100,    0]])
```

I cant even think where I should start.

It will be awesome if someone can help.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need? What's the output you want from this for instance?

Comment: that's what I'm trying to understand too.. that's just how the question was worded. So I guess I just have to return how many cells in the csv file is either blank, nan or 0.

Comment: should be `data = np.array([[   1, 2000,  143, 4546], [   2, 1999,  246,    0], [   3, 2008,  190,   np.NAN ], [   4, 2000,  100,    0]])`

Comment: but some of the real data do have some blanks like that. no?

Comment: If you tell numpy that it's a numerical array, it can't then store a blank since that implies `""` which is a string.  The blank would have to be interpreted as a NaN.

Comment: I tweaked my answer to better follow the DRY principle.  Save the slice and then rather than re-slicing for each part of the statement, just operate on the sliced array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to be able to access just the column that you're interested in.  Do this with a slice:

```
data[:,2] # grab all rows, and just the column with index 2
```

Now you want to count the occurrences that are `NaN`:

```
np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(data[:,2]))
```

And we want to count the number of zero elements:

```
data[:,2].size - np.count_nonzero(data[:,2])
```

And if we add those together:

```
data[:,2].size - np.count_nonzero(data[:,2]) + np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(data[:,2]))
```

This is boring, though, since the 3rd column doesn't have any `0` or `NaN` in it.  Lets try with the last column:

```
>>> slice = data[:,3]
>>> slice.size - np.count_nonzero(slice) + np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(slice))
3
```

---

**edit** I should explain why this works:

`np.isnan(data[:,2])` gives an array of `True` and `False` based on if it's a `NaN` or not.  `True`, when treated as a number, is converted to `1` and `False is converted to`0`so the`np.count_nonzero`call counts the number of`1`which represent the`NaN` values.

`np.count_nonzero(data[:,2])` counts the number of non-zero directly.  If we subtract the number of non-zero elements from the total number of elements, we'll get the number of `0`s.

Comment: hey thank you so much. I have tried this code on my real csv data. and I tested on the several column that has 0s in it. but I am getting one more count than the actual count. 

so if there are 54 0s in one column then I get 55 somehow.

Comment: Try running the the three parts by themselves to see which one is giving the wrong number.  So `slice.size`, then `np.count_nonzero(slice)` then `np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(slice))`.